# Chamar classe Java (.JAR) utilizando C++ (.EXE)?

Tags: java, c++

Tenho uma aplicação Java (SISTEMA.JAR) com a classe de entrada do sistema ... Ok?

Para tornar mais transparente para o usuário final, gostaria de criar um .EXE em C++ compilado que apenas chamasse a classe Java.

É possivel ?

Qual compilador C++ sugerido? (o menor possível, visto a complexidade)

Obrigado.

Lúcio

Comment: Qual vantagem real você espera ter com isto? Não vai mudar nada. Se quer apenas que ele chame a classe automaticamente pode registrar a extensão para chamar o Java sozinho ou fazer um arquivo *batch* para chamar. Não imagino como a criação de um executável só para chamar o Java seja melhor que isto.

Comment: Partilho da opinião do @bigown, isso não é nem um pouco prático. Outra coisa, não tem como você chamar uma classe java em outra linguagem, o máximo que você poderia fazer é chamar o arquivo .jar e deixar a JVM carregar a sua classe de entrada.

Comment: Entendo o ponto de vista de cada uma das respostas.
Mas ainda gostaria de fazer um teste, ficando transparente para o usuário a tecnologia utilizada.
E ai ? Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Como dito nos comentários, isso não é prático e não faz tanto sentido até para o usuário final. O que eu posso te recomendar é criar um instalador que extraia os arquivos do seu programa em uma pasta e crie um atalho para o ".jar" no Desktop. Ou se você mesmo for integrar o sistema em cada máquina que ele for utilizado, simplesmente crie o atalho no Desktop.

Mas, em resposta às perguntas originais...

"É possível?" Sim.

"Qual o compilador sugerido?" MinGW.

Exemplo:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    std::system("java -jar 'caminho-do-programa/Sistema.jar'");
    return 0;
}
```

Isso irá iniciar a aplicação .jar e irá fechar seu mini-programa em C++.